# Is deprecating all single record operations with multiple record operations a good idea?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rest, graphql, apollo

**TL;DR**

Look at code examples and tell me which one would you choose.

**The entire thing**

I am in progress of making an GraphQL API. Amid doing that, I have realized, that I'd love to mass insert data, but I could not, because the only method available to me was the one used for single item insertion. This revealed a problem. If someone was to insert higher volumes of data, they would either have to send single item requests one by one, or I have to add another mutation that allows array of items as an input. As the first option is for apparent reasons not an option. This meant adding another method, but this got me thinking, why should I even be keeping single operations methods (get/update/add single item) in the first place, as they do exactly the same, just with the limitation of sending max 1 item, are harder to maintain, and pollute API documentation.

My question is, would you go ahead and replace all those single operation methods with a multiple operation method?

To me it's a no-brainer and the answer is yes. The reason why am I asking is, that vast majority of APIs does have the above described structure of using one endpoint for responding with singular item and one for responding with multiple items and I bet there is a reason for it.

**Code example** of what I mean:

Deprecating this:

```js
/*=============================================
                    Types
=============================================*/
interface UpdateDog {
    _id: string,
    name: string
}
interface AddDog {
    name: string
}
/*=============================================
                    Main
=============================================*/
export const DogModule = {
    resolvers: {
        Query: {
            dog: async (parents: any, args: { _id: string }) => {
                // Returns one of only one ID is passed in array
            },
            dogs: async (parents: any, args: { _ids: string[] }) => {
                // Returns dogs
            },
            allDogs: async () => {
                // Returns all dogs
            }
        },
        Mutation: {
            addDog: async (parents: any, args: { input: AddDog}, context: GraphqlContext) => {
                // Add dog to the database
            },
            addDogs: async (parents: any, args: { input: AddDog[] }, context: GraphqlContext) => {
                // Add dogs to the database
            },
            updateDog: async (parents: any, args: { input: UpdateDog }, context: GraphqlContext) => {
                // Update dog
            },
            updateDogs: async (parents: any, args: { input: UpdateDog[] }, context: GraphqlContext) => {
                // Update dogs
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}

export default DogModule
```

In favor of this:

```js
/*=============================================
                    Types
=============================================*/
interface UpdateDog {
    _id: string,
    name: string
}
interface AddDog {
    name: string
}
/*=============================================
                    Main
=============================================*/
export const DogModule = {
    resolvers: {
        Query: {
            dogs: async (parents: any, args: { _ids: string[] }) => {
                // Returns one of only one ID is passed in array
                // Multiple on multiple IDs
                // All if not IDs are passed
            }
        },
        Mutation: {
            addDogs: async (parents: any, args: { input: AddDog[] }, context: GraphqlContext) => {
                // Add them to the database
            },
            updateDogs: async (parents: any, args: { input: UpdateDog[] }, context: GraphqlContext) => {
                // Update dogs
            },
            ...
        }
    }
}

export default DogModule
```

Additional info:

- Once done API will be a publicly accessible with API key. Meaning that I will be able to limit the amount of changes coming from one source.
- I am aware that I cannot replace every single operation method multi operation method. (such as logins, or signup)

Comment: Why not allow array or a single input with a union type? The return type is based on the input.

Comment: Forgot to add a link on how to define custom scalars for union input types: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/custom-scalars/